# how to give textcolor to textview in class file

Tags: android, custom-controls

I am creating the custom textview i want to give  black textcolor to this textview. how can i set textcolor. my code is

TextView textview = new TextView(this);

textview.setText("Please follow this Description");

setContentView(_textview);

when i use textview.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#000000"))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Color.parseColor():

```
textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

another option is to use HEX integer directly:

```
textview.setTextColor(0xff000000);
```

Comment: The code allows you to set not only predefined colors, but any color in formats of #RRGGBB or #AARRGGBB

Comment: According to this answer how can i set my text to bold.

Comment: Thanks  Konstantin Burov Its Really help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it is done by using the code

textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);