# different behaviour creating layout using xml / java

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to reproduce the behaviour of this simple layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#0000ff"/>
```

a linearlayout with blue background taking all the available space.

I can't understand why this java code doesn't work ? the screen stays black. can somebody advise ?

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this, null);
layout.setBackgroundColor(0xff);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
setContentView(layout);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set color correctly, look at [how to give textcolor to textview in class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572773/how-to-give-textcolor-to-textview-in-class-file/3572841#3572841) for example.

Comment: thank you very much !

    layout.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.BLUE);

Answer (score 0):

0xff in code is a transparent blue color :) Use 0xff0000ff.